# concatenate array to bits

Tags: c, concatenation, shift

How can I achieve the following concatenation of 1s and 0s of low the density array `data` into a smaller more densely filled array `c`

```
uint8_t data[16] = {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
uint8_t c[2] = {0};
/*  desired result
    c[0] = 11011011
    c[1] = 10001101 
*/
```

I am a little bit struggeling here, up to now, I have got it like, but it does not seem to work like I expected:

```
static void compress(unsigned char *out, unsigned char *in, int length)
{
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if((i+1)%9==0)
            out++;
        *out |= in[i]<<((length-i)%9);

    }
}  
int main(){
    compress(c,data,16);
    printf("%d",c[0]); //should be 219
    printf("%d",c[1]); //should be 177 (edit)
}
```

thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one line to your code `printf ("%d %d\n", i,(length-i)%9 );` and you see where the problem is.

Don't use modulo operation, add variable which helds the bit-shift number (initial value is 7) and reset it when it is negative:

```
static void compress2(unsigned char *out, unsigned char *in, int length)
{
    int shift = 7;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        *out |= in[i] << shift;
        if (--shift < 0)
        {
            ++out;
            shift = 7;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, worked! endianess turned out to be different, so i started with shift=0 and incremented it, until ++shift > 7 when i set shift to 0 again.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void compress(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in, size_t length)
{
    memset(out, 0, length >> 3 + !!(length & 7));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        out[i >> 3] |= (in[i] << (7 - (i & 7)));
        //out[i >> 3] |= ((!!in[i]) << (7 - (i & 7)));  - if array elements may be not only 0 or 1.
    }
}  

int main()
{
    uint8_t data[16] = {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
    uint8_t c[sizeof(data) >> 3 + !!(sizeof(data) & 7)];

    compress(c,data,16);
    printf("%d\n",c[0]); //should be 219
    printf("%d\n",c[1]); //should be 141
}
```

Comment: thank you, like the other solutions, this worked fine as well

Answer (score 1):

Size of unit8_t is only 8 bits, not 9. So fundamentally, the error is in %9 instead of %8.

---

You can use separate counter (b) for bit shift amount from 7 down to 0. Once it reaches -1, advance out. Start with (length-1), because for length 1 you want it to be lowest bit, that is with shift amount 0.

```
static void compress(unsigned char *out, unsigned char *in, int length)
{
    for(int* p=in, int b=(length-1)%8; p<in+length; p++, b--)
    {
        if(b < 0)
        {
            out++;
            b = 7;
        }
        *out |= *p << b;
    }
}
```

---

Also you can use something like out[(length-i-1) / 8] |= in[i] << (length-i-1) % 8

---

P.S. Bit order is platform dependant...

Comment: thank you! also a valid solution, also thank you for the endianess hint